# kivy GridLayout and AnchorLayout

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, grid-layout

I'm writing a program, using kivy, to display 4 images on the screen.
The target window I want to get is like this:
[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsfEu.jpg)

where the background of the window is white, and 4 images are depicted by green rectangles.The screen ratio is 16:9, but the image ratio is 4:3. I want to stick these 4 images to the center of the screen.

I tried with using GridLayout and AnchorLayout, the code is given below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MainScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.float_list = []
        self.anchor_list = []
        self.image_list = []
        self.rows = 2

        for i in range(4):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                self.anchor_list.append(AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right'))
            else:
                self.anchor_list.append(AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left'))

            self.image_list.append(Image(source='./tmp_pics/1.jpg'))

            self.anchor_list[i].add_widget(self.image_list[i])
            self.add_widget(self.anchor_list[i])

class MainDisplay(App):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainDisplay, self).__init__()

    def build(self):

        self.mainScreen = MainScreen()

        return self.mainScreen

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1600')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '900')

    app = MainDisplay()
    app.run()
```

But the result I got is:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBgFZ.jpg)

Please anyone can help me to obtain the requirement above?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to put all of those images in a single grid layout, which would be then centered in the middle of a screen:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

gui = '''
Screen:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 2
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        MyImage
        MyImage
        MyImage
        MyImage

<MyImage@AsyncImage>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 200
    source: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/'
'''


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(gui)


Test().run()
```